# flutter problems w/ Future<http.Response>

Tags: http, flutter, xmlhttprequest, response, httpresponse

I have problems with the return type "Response". I don't really know how to handle that type. 
Do I have to convert it. I just want to display the response to the screen.

Can someone please explain the problem?

```
  var username = 'dslf-config';
  var password = '53259721';
  static String port = "37443";
  String url = 'https://192.168.2.1:' + port;
  //unused.... String parameter = 'Device.DeviceInfo.ModelName';

  var body = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" ?>
    <soap-env:Envelope soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsaop.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cwmp="urn:telekom-de.totr64-2-n">
        <soap-env:Body>
            <cwmp:GetParameterValues xmlns:cwmp="urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0">
                <cwmp:ParameterNames soap-env:arrayType="xsd:string[10]">
                    <xsd:string>Device.DeviceInfo.ModelName</xsd:string>
                </cwmp:ParameterNames>
            </cwmp:GetParameterValues>
        </soap-env:Body>
    </soap-env:Envelope>""";

  Future<http.Response> getData2() {
    bool trustSelfSigned = true;
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Content-Type": "text/xml",
      "SOAPAction":
          "urn:telekom-de:device:TO_InternetGatewayDevice:2#GetParameterValues"
    };

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => trustSelfSigned);

    httpClient.addCredentials(Uri.parse(url), "theRealm",
        new HttpClientDigestCredentials(username, password));

    IOClient ioClient = new IOClient(httpClient);

    return ioClient.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers, body: body); 
  }

  getData3() async {
    final response = await getData2();
    print(response.body);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.headers);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your issue is. If you want the body of your response to be displayed in your app, you can simply put it in a `Text` widget, something like `Text(response.body)`.

If it's about HTTP responses, then I suggest you read an article about how HTTP requests and responses work. The `http.Response` class in Flutter simply parses a raw HTTP response and presents it to the user.